# "How did you get in here? Security!" vs "How have you gotten in here? Security!"

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past, present-perfect-vs-simple-past

I have been doing some exercises on Past Simple vs Present Perfect as that's the topic that gives me the most troubles... and I can't comprehend why this sentence is correct?

> "How **did you get** in here? Security!"

Someone has broken in somewhere and another person is calling security, so it's **relevant to the present**, because he's still inside, about to be captured. According to this logic it should be sentence in Present Perfect ("How **have you gotten** in here? Security!"), but the answer in the book is to use Past Simple.

Also google shows that "How have you gotten in here" has only 8 results while "How did you get in here" has 3.5 million so it's much more popular "version".

Comment: This advice about using the perfect if it's relevant to the present is really a very bad guide as to exactly when you should use the perfect. At some level, **everything** is relevant to the present.

Comment: @PeterShor Compare "I lived there for six years" to "I have lived there for six years." Only the latter means that you *still* live there.

Comment: The person got  into the place at a specific point in time. The fact he is still there is irrelevant. VERSUS How have you  gotten in here this week? Over a time period.

Comment: Note that 'gotten' is pretty much exclusively US usage, BrE doesn't use it. It's gained a little popularity in recent times as the UK has been exposed to more US media content.

Comment: And now in the US we're saying "bespoke" and "spot on" and "done and dusted".

Answer (score 0):

*How **have** you **gotten** in?* would be more appropriate in a context like this

> I saw you get in today through the window. But that’s only just been installed, and you say this wasn’t your first breaking-in. **How have you gotten in** before?

Note too that in my example, the use of *have gotten* results in the nuance of requesting an enumeration of the various routes and methods of entry, whereas *did get* feels as though the speaker is more likely to imagine a single way that was used on all the previous occasions.

All of this is pretty subtle, but it’s what a native speaker of American English feels in the gut.

Comment: Right, the before governs the present perfect here.

Comment: I would have to disagree with your statement that the present perfect would imply a more complicated break-in strategy than the simple past does. I think you're projecting the complications of the tense onto the break-in itself. The present perfect certainly feels cumbersome in context, and Security is far more likely to be blunt: How did you get in?

Comment: Clearly the idea is to make it sound as strange as possible; that's what the perfect is for. _How might you have gotten in here? Security!_